# How to get access to beta testing of Azure Platform?

Tags: .net, azure, cloud

I have a [small web product](http://blog.readytocloud.com) develop in MS .NET with Azure SDK used.  I have tested the project in my local machine with the Azure UI Locally installed but I will like to try it out in the Azure platform itself.  Is there anything special that we have to do to obtain access to the [Azure Beta Platform](http://blog.readytocloud.com/2009/06/windows-azure-platform-microsoft.html)?.

[Azure Developer Portal http://cp.images.s3.amazonaws.com/ForumImages/cp-6-8-2009PM-01.png](http://cp.images.s3.amazonaws.com/ForumImages/cp-6-8-2009PM-01.png)

As you can see in the picture above I have Live Framework calls and Existing APIs available but I have zero (0) hosted services available.  I hope the picture illustrate more for people helping out in this forum.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you receive a token in email after registering?  It should take about one business day to get a token.  If you didn't and think you should have, you can email me (Steve.Marx@microsoft.com), and I'll look into it for you.

The place you upload your app is http://lx.azure.microsoft.com.  http://dev.windowsazure.com has a few other useful resources.

Answer (score 1):

You have to [register](http://www.microsoft.com/azure/register.mspx).

Comment: Thanks JP.  Yes I registered, also watch the initial video, read the SDK documentation.  That is why I thought I was ready to deploy my web app there, but find out myself looking were to publish the files on the azure platform.

Comment: Yup, once you get the email as Steve described, you log in and can create a new project.